# Why do we need a bootloader in an embedded device?

Tags: linux, embedded, arm, bootloader

I'm working with ELinux kernel on ARM cortex-A8.

I know how the bootloader works and what job it's doing. But i've got a question - why do we need bootloader, **why was the bootloader born**?

Why we can't directly load the kernel into RAM from flash memory without bootloader? If we load it what will happen? In fact, processor will not support it, but why are we following the procedure?

Comment: "Why we cant directly load the kernel into RAM from flash memory" - that is *exactly* what bootloader is doing.

Comment: Bartek is right. DIY and I'm pretty sure it's what we call bootloader.

Comment: Even if the code is run directly from flash on-chip, how are you going to load the flash memory?  You probably need some firmware to load the flash...

Comment: If you know how it works, you should be able to understand why it is needed.

Comment: You dont need a bootloader at all, you CAN simply copy the kernel and root file system into ram, setup a few ATAGS and branch to ram. Booting linux is somewhat trivial.  The bootloader is to help with development and debugging, but is not required (so long as you have dram init and other hardware init in some software somewhere, often that is done in the bootloader).

Comment: @MartinJames - chips with onboard flash memory are usually flashable by a means such as JTAG extensions or SWD, which interacts with hardware state machines to do the flashing rather than with bootloader code running on the CPU.  Some of these also have bootloader modes that can program the flash or download code from an external data interface.  I can't think of any general purpose CPU which where the bootloader is your only option on a fresh chip, though burning fuses could make it so.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I've seen some 8-pin Freescale HC08 derivatives which ship from the factory with a boot loader in flash.  User code may if desired either leave the boot loader in place or store and run a program in RAM which replaces the boot loader with more user code.  If user code does the latter, there will no longer be any manufacturer-specified means of changing the code on the chip (though user code might provide for its own means).

Comment: @supercat - are you certain that said HC08 parts do not support freescale's ICS08 in circuit programming interface?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I remember the documentation specifying that if a chip got programmed with invalid start-up firmware it was hosed.  It's possible that it only meant to imply that the chip would be unusable by people whose "programmer" was just a serial interface, but if that were the case I would think the documentation would have said the chips would be unusable unless or until they were reburned using suitable programming hardware, rather than suggesting the condition would be permanent.

Comment: Maybe you are not wondering a traditional boot loader, but the really complex u-boot with an entire Linux kernel, are you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A boot loader is a computer program that loads the main operating system or runtime environment for the computer after completion of the self-tests.

^ <sub>From [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader#Boot_loader)</sub>

So basically bootloader is doing just what you wanted - copying data from flash into operating memory. It's really that simple.

If you want to know more about boostrapping the OS, I highly recommend you read the linked article. Boot phase consists, apart from tests, also of checking peripherals and some other things. Skipping them makes sense only on very simple embedded devices, and that's why their bootloaders are even simpler:

> Some embedded systems do not require a noticeable boot sequence to begin functioning and when turned on may simply run operational programs that are stored in ROM.

<sub>The same source</sub>

Comment: While the *Wikipedia* article is useful, it is focused on PC (in the larger sense) boot loaders.  Embedded/ARM/Linux platform have some additional issues.  Embedded ARM's CPUs have features to reduce component count; specifically eliminating the ROM/NOR flash that typically holds PC BIOS reduces cost.  This portion is most relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader#Other_kinds_of_boot_sequences

Answer (score 17):

In the context of Linux, the boot loader is responsible for some predefined tasks.  As this question is [arm](/questions/tagged/arm) tagged, I think that [ARM booting](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/booting.rst) might be a useful resource.  Specifically, the boot loader was/is responsible for setting up an `ATAG` list that describing the amount of RAM, a kernel command line, and other parameters.  One of the most important parameters is the *machine type*.  With *device trees*, an entire description of the board is passed.  This makes a stock ARM Linux impossible to boot with out some code to setup the parameters as described.

The parameters allows one *generic* Linux to support multiple devices.  For instance, an ARM Debian kernel can support hundreds of different board types.  **Uboot** or other boot loader can dynamically determine this information or it can be hard coded for the board.

You might also like to look at [bootloader info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bootloader/info) page here at stack overflow.

A basic system might be able to setup `ATAGS` and copy NOR flash to SRAM.  However, it is usually a little more complex than this.  Linux needs RAM setup, so you may have to initialize an SDRAM controller.  If you use NAND flash, you have to handle *bad blocks* and the *copy* may be a little more complex than `memcpy()`.

Linux often has some latent driver bugs where a driver will assume that a clock is initialized.  For instance if **Uboot** always initializes an Ethernet clock for a particular machine, the Linux Ethernet driver may have neglected to setup this clock.  This can be especially true with clock trees.

Some systems require boot image formats that are not supported by Linux; for example a special header which can initialize hardware immediately; like configuring the `devices` to read initial code from.  Additionally, often there is hardware that should be configured immediately; a *boot loader* can do this quickly whereas the normal structure of Linux may delay this significantly resulting in I/O conflicts, etc.

From a pragmatic perspective, it is simpler to use a boot loader.  However, there is nothing to prevent you from altering Linux's source to boot directly from it; although it maybe like pasting the *boot loader* code directly to the start of Linux.

See Also: [Coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot), [Uboot](http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot), and [Wikipedia's comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders). [Barebox](http://www.barebox.org/) is a lesser known, but well structured and modern boot loader for the ARM.  [RedBoot](http://ecos.sourceware.org/redboot/) is also used in some ARM systems; RedBoot partitions are supported in the kernel tree.

Comment: Files in [*arch/arm/boot/compressed*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed) are a way to boot without a bootloader.  However, they are for machines that were in the early history of ARM Linux and this is no longer supported; but you could in theory do a similar thing; write your own *head-machine.S* which setup DDR and ran from the 'reset vector'.  In fact, it maybe easier with a modern ARM Linux and an **attached DTB**.

Comment: Another important feature of bootloaders is POST (power on self test) and recovery; allowing for an upgrade/replacement of a bad kernel update.  It is often used by manufacturing to perform hardware tests to verify proper assembly before shipping to a customer.  POST will check that memory is functioning before loading an OS.  Typical boot loaders maybe able to run in an internal SRAM or other high reliability memory device.

Answer (score 6):

The primary bootloader is usually built in into the silicon and performs the load of the first USER code that will be run in the system.

The bootloader exists because there is no standardized protocol for loading the first code, since it is chip dependent. Sometimes the code can be loaded through a serial port, a flash memory, or even a hard drive. It is bootloader function to locate it.

Once the user code is loaded and running, the bootloader is no longer used and the correctness of the system execution is user responsibility.

In the embedded linux chain, the primary bootloader will setup and run the Uboot. Then Uboot will find the linux kernel and load it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why we can't directly load the kernel into RAM from flash memory without bootloader? If we load it what will happen? In fact, processor will not support it, but why are we following the procedure?

Bartek, Artless, and Felipe all give parts of the picture.

Every embedded processor type (E.G. 386EX, Coretex-A53, EM5200) will do ***something*** automatically when it is reset or powered on.  Sometimes that ***something*** is different depending on whether the power is cycled or the device is reset.  Some embedded processors allow you to change that ***something*** based on voltages applied to different pins when the device is powered or reset.

Regardless, there is a limited amount of ***something*** that a processor can do, because of the physical space on-processor required to define that ***something***, whether it is on-chip FLASH, instruction micro-code, or some other mechanism.

This limit means that the ***something*** is

- fixed purpose, does one thing as quickly as possible.
- limited in scope and capability, typically loading a small block of code (often a few kilobytes or less) into a fixed memory location and executing from the start of the loaded code.
- unmodifiable.

So what a processor does in response to reset or power-cycle cannot be changed, and cannot do very much, and we don't want it to automatically copy hundreds of megabytes or gigabytes into memory which may not exist or may not be initialized, and which could take a looooong time.

So....

We set up a small program which is smaller than the smallest size permitted across all of the devices we are going to use.  That program is stored wherever the ***something*** needs it to be.

Sometimes the small program is U-Boot.  Sometimes even U-Boot is too big for initial load, so the small program then in turn loads U-Boot.

The point is that whatever gets loaded by the ***something***, is ***modifiable*** as needed for a particular system.  If it is U-Boot, great, if not, it knows where to load the main operating system or where to load U-Boot (or some other bootloader).

U-Boot (speaking of bootloaders in general) then configures a minimal set of devices, memory, chip settings, etc., to enable the main OS to be loaded and started.  The main OS init takes care of any additional configuration or initialization.

So the sequence is:

- Processor power-on or reset
- ***Something*** loads initial boot code (or U-Boot style embedded bootloader)
- Initial boot code (may not be needed)
- U-Boot (or other general embedded bootloader)
- Linux init

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what is stated in all the other answers - which is correct - in some cases the system has to go through different execution modes, take as example TrustZone for secure ARM chips. It is possible to still consider it as sort of HW initialization, but what makes it peculiar is the fact that there are additional limitations (ex: memory available) that make it impractical, if not impossible, to do everything in a single binary, thus multiple stages of bootloader are available.

Furthermore, for security reason, each of them is signed and can perform its job only if it meets the security requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel requires the hardware on which you are working to be in a particular state. All the hardware you used needs to be checked for its state and initialized for its further operation. This is one of the main reasons to use a boot loader in an embedded (or any other environment), apart from its use to load a kernel image into the RAM.
When you turn on a system, the RAM is also not in a useful state (fully initialized to use) for us to load kernel into it. Therefore, we cannot load a kernel directly (to answer your question)and thus arises the need for a construct to initialize it.